# angular send cookies from http request to php

Tags: php, angularjs, cookies

so this question ask several time but still i could't figure this out. i'm sending http request from angular app to php service. and i need access the cookies i set from the browser. i know that to access cookies from php service i have to set the **withCredentials** in my http request. but then again **wilcard** error raised.

here is the http request

```
$http({
    url : $scope.urlDomain+ "setting/getAll?skip=0&take=10&orderby=asc",
    method :"POST",
    headers : {
        securityToken : "1124"
    },
    withCredentials: true 
})
```

i had set the headers in my php file

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT,POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type, securityToken");
```

this is the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/services/getAll?skip=0&take=10&orderby=asc. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute
```

i stuck in this over day and still could't figure this out. thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ");` when you enable `withCredentials`, you have to specify a domain like this:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 127.0.0.1");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: domain2");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: domain3");
```

Comment: can i use multiple domains

Comment: @IT13122256RanawakaR.A.S.M You will have to add multiple rules, i've updated my answer

Comment: thank man. i found a solution to get the host dynamically using this **header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}")**

Comment: @IT13122256RanawakaR.A.S.M It's unsafe to accept every host though, I would make a whitelist and check if the origin is on that list, otherwise deny it